# duda codigo excel

Tags: excel, vba

Vereis tengo un codigo en excel que me guarda y cierra la hoja despues de un tiempo de inactividad pero los archivos con los que trabajo estan cifrados asi que al guardar me sale un ventana emergente en la que le tengo que hacer click a ok para guardar sabeis de alguna forma de hacer esto de forma automatica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente te baste con desactivar las alertas de Excel

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Comment: El programa que me manda la alerta no es excel me servira igual?

Comment: No entiendo, la pregunta decía "codigo en excel ", lo debes ejecutar tal como el resto del VBA

Comment: la pregunta es si ese codigo funcionara con una ventana emergente que no pertenece al codigo

Comment: Si hace referencia al Excel, da igual donde lo ejecutes, aunque sin ver el código no puedo asegurar nada

Comment: hay alguna manera de hacer que el ordenador pulse la tecla enter despues de que el excel ejecute la macro que me guarda y cierra el arxivo despues de un tiempo de inactividad?

Comment: Hola, tienes esto (https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys) que utiliza SendKeys. Aunque no es muy recomendable puede sacarte del apuro.